# Dragging Importrange down rows and having cells change in line in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hi here is the formula I am using

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14nKbr2vekTgo11li0EdzXpHl2urIg721rcgD0eOSWTM/edit?usp=sharing","Form Responses 1!b2:r2")
```

this is in row 2, I want to drag it down so that in row 3 it shows b3:R3 and so on

For reference, I need the data to stop at R2, there are separate formulas in S and T

Comment: Use `"Form Responses 1!b2:r` which will automatically pull all data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to drag from row#2

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14nKbr2vekTgo11li0EdzXpHl2urIg721rcgD0eOSWTM/edit?usp=sharing","Form Responses 1!b"&row()&":r"&row())
```